# rsync from development to production - ownership/permissions - PermitRootLogin

Tags: permissions, rsync, development

In order to use "`rsync`" to synchronize data between a development server and a production server, I have to set `PermitRootLogin on` on the production server, then I can run "`rsync -avhe ssh --delete --progress local/folder root@192.168.10.120:/home/www/folder/`", to keep all files with ownership/permissions unchanged.

However, because of the security policy, I have to set "`PermitRootLogin no`" on the production server.

What would be a good way of dealing with this problem?

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for both answers! for now I end up pulling them from the development server.

Answer (score 1):

trigger your mirror on the production server to the development server.

Comment: could you elaborate a bit more about this? thanks

Comment: I think what he's saying is run rsync on the production server and have it pull from the development server, instead of the other way around.

Comment: Yes - "PermitRootLogin no" everywhere and "rsync -avhe ssh --delete --progress someuser@devbox:/local/folder /home/www/folder/" as root on the production. (:s/to/from/g <karmawhore)

Answer (score 0):

create dedicated user for rsync and make it member of root group (GID 0 )